# Is it normal for a motion sensor to heat up when idle?

Tags: motion-sensor

I have a wall-plugged night light with lighting and motion sensors. It has three possible states:

1. When the room is lit up, all LEDs are off.
2. When the room is dark but there is no motion, only one LED is on.
3. When the room is dark and there is motion, all LEDs turn on.

The thing works, but with a weird side effect: its case heats up palpably around the sensors in state 1 only. The temperature feels like a phone's back when in active use.

Is it normal or should I be worried? I also have two night lights with lighting sensors only - they do not heat up at all. So the issue may be specific to motion sensors, or it may be just faulty electronics. Any input appreciated.

Comment: Where was it made?

Comment: @SolarMike Do you mean the county? According to the label, it's UK made in China. Kingfisher.